# How to get list of possible replacements in string using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have the following strings:

```
4563_1_some_data
```

The general pattern is

```
r'\d{1,5}_[1-4]_some_data
```

Note, that numbers before first underscore may be the same for different **some_data** 
So the question is: how to get all possible variants of replacement using regex? 
Desired output:

```
[4563_1_some_data, 4563_2_some_data, 4563_3_some_data, 4563_4_some_data]
```

My attempt:

```
[re.sub(r'_\d_', r'_[1-4]_', row).group() for row in data]
```

But it has result:

```
4563_[1-4]_some_data
```

Seems like ordinary replacement. How should I activate pattern replacement and get the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over a range object to create your list.

1. Create that `range` object: To do that you need a pattern to get the `[1-4]` part from your pattern.
2. You'll need another pattern to replace the number in the actual data with the variable from range object.

```py
import re

text = "4563_1_some_data"
original_pattern = r"\d{1,5}_[1-4]_some_data"

# A regex to get the `[1-4]` part.
find_numbers_pattern = r"(?<=_)\[(\d)\-(\d)\](?=_)"

# Get `1` and `4` to create a range object
a, b = map(int, re.search(find_numbers_pattern, original_pattern).groups())

# Use `count=` to only change the first match.
lst = [re.sub(r"(?<=_)\d(?=_)", str(i), text, count=1) for i in range(a, b + 1)]

print(lst)
```

output:

```
['4563_1_some_data', '4563_2_some_data', '4563_3_some_data', '4563_4_some_data']
```

###### `(?<=_)\[(\d)\-(\d)\](?=_)` explanation:

`(?<=_)`: A positive lookbehind assertion to match `_`.

`\[(\d)\-(\d)\]`: to get the `[1-4]` for example.

`(?=_)`: A positive lookahead assertion to find the `_`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's actually what I've searched!

Answer (score 2):

Regex replacement may not be the most appropriate tool for your requirement.  Instead, consider using f strings as follows:

```py
def repl(inp, nums):
    parts = re.split(r'_\d+_', inp)
    output = [parts[0] + f'_{x}_' + parts[1] for x in nums]
    return(output)

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
inp = '4563_1_some_data'
output = repl(inp, nums)
print(output)

# ['4563_1_some_data', '4563_2_some_data', '4563_3_some_data', '4563_4_some_data']
```

Comment: That's solution seems much simpler for my specific task, but less general than @S.B suggested

Comment: I have edited my answer to be more generic.  You shouldn't need regex here, actually.